# How can I use [self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:] method in +(void)classMethod

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How can I use `[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:]` method in `+(void)classMethod`?

I've got a sprite defined in the following:

```
+(void)classMethod
{
   CCSprite * sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite.png"];

  //and hope afterDelay3.0second remove this sprite

   [self performSelector:@select(clean:) withObject:sprite afterDelay:3.0];
}

+(void)clean:(CCSprite *)sprite
{
   [sprite removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: Looks like you did use it. What's the problem?

Comment: it just for example this code get crash

Comment: Uh, you're using "self" in a class method.

Comment: @HotLicks: So? That's perfectly valid.

Comment: @ryuikuya: What's the crash? Show us the stack trace. As written, there's no obvious error.

Comment: I'M sorry . I found the crash it's another reason. this method can be perform. thank you everyone'help

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- What does "self" in a class method point to?  Certainly not an instance of the class.

Comment: @HotLicks: `self` in a class method refers to the instance of `Class` representing the class itself. So `[self something]` in a class method calls the class method `+something`, and `[super something]` calls the superclass' implementation.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- Right.  But do class objects implement a `clean` method that expects a `CCSprite`?

Comment: @ryuikuya, Just check my answer. you will know why your code is not working.

Comment: @Owl ok I'm checking it. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically `self` refers to the `Object` of given class, In your case you are not creating an `Object` so you won't be able to call `Object` methods from static method.

**Visual**

[image]

A quick test shows that, If you method is declared instance level then you will not be able to access it from your class method.

In your case,

```
+(void)classMethod
{

}
```

is a class method but,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(clean:) withObject:sprite afterDelay:3.0];
```

is an instance method of `NSObject`, That is why you are not able to call from your class method.

### [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

That means you are accessing instance method from class method, which is not allowed.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether he's creating an object, but rather whether he's in an instance method.  He's not, so `self`, if it's valid at all, is pointing at the class object, not an instance of the class.

Comment: This is incorrect. On a class method, `self` refers to the class (not an instance).

Comment: Both methods are class methods.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan, I respect your suggestion, but why the quick test shows that I am correct?

Comment: Because you have a typo. In the OP's code, both methods are class methods (indicated by the `+`) but in your code, one is an instance method (`-`).

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan, I guess I am right, the clean method is class method but before that perform method is an instance method of NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use this `Instance` method in another `Class` method.

If you want to do some delay action, try `NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` instead.

Comment: +1, @Selkie, You are absolutely correct and your given suggestion is the perfect way of doing this. Dont worry!